# How to dynamically allocate all months based to a column on condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I am storing the `Product Name` and it's `Renewal Date` along with the payment plan `(Monthly/Quarterly/Yearly)`. Now if the payment plan of the product is `Yearly or Monthly` it will display the get the month of Renewal and show the `Rate/Amount` against that month but if the payment plan is `Monthly` it should display the `Rate/Amount` in front of each month as shown below.

For example if a product named `ABC` has payment plan of `Yearly`, subscription rate of `276` and `Renewal Date` `2019-12-01` and there is another product `XYZ` with payment plan of `Monthly`, subscription rate of `17` and `Renewal Date` `2019-08-15` then the result set I want should something like this

```
ProductName    RenewalMonth   Rate
------------------------------------
ABC            December       276
XYZ            January         17
XYZ            February        17
XYZ            March           17
XYZ            April           17
XYZ            May             17
XYZ            June            17
XYZ            July            17
XYZ            August          17
XYZ            September       17
XYZ            October         17
XYZ            November        17
XYZ            December        17
```

Here is the query which I have wrote which is returning data that's present in the database fine but not the months other than December for `Product XYZ`. Keeping in mind this should only display same rate for all other months provided in the desired dates where Payment Plan is `'Monthly'`, for other payment plans it should show rate in front of given month as present in the database.

Sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemDefinition 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    PaymentPlan VARCHAR(50),
    RenewalDate DATETIME,
    UnitRate NUMERIC(18, 0)
);

INSERT INTO ItemDefinition 
VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'Yearly', '2019-12-01', 276),
       (1, 'XYZ', 'Monthly', '2019-08-15', 17);
```

And the query I am writing is

```
SELECT 
    ProductName, SUM(UnitRate) Rate,
    DATENAME(MONTH , DATEADD(MONTH , MONTH(RenewalDate)-1 , '1900-01-01')) RenewalMonth
FROM
    ItemDefinition 
WHERE 
    MONTH(RenewalDate) IS NOT NULL
    AND RenewalDate BETWEEN @dtStart AND @dtEnd
GROUP BY 
    ProductName, MONTH(RenewalDate)
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(RenewalDate)
```

[image: As shown in this picture '<code>Office 365 Essential</code>' has <code>Monthly</code> subscription as per my record so it has to be displayed under each month.]

Comment: you can get all months using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155821/7124761) and as per your desired output it must be ABC - monthly and XYZ as yearly while insert!

Comment: @gotqn I am creating a report which has to show the history record too so for that purpose it should start from the provided date. Yearly subscription cannot be turned into months because it's yearly and client wishes to pay after 1 year not every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be something like this:

```
DECLARE @DateBeg DATE = '2019-01-01'
       ,@DateEnd DAte = '2020-12-01';


WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,@DateBeg AS [DateBeg]
          ,@DateEnd AS [DateEnd]
    FROM ItemDefinition DS
)
SELECT *
      ,DATENAME(MONTH ,ISNULL([GeneratedDate], [RenewalDate])) AS RenewalMonth
FROM Ranges
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg])
    FROM 
    (
        select number 
        from master.dbo.spt_values
        where [type] = 'P'
    ) numbers
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg]) < [DateEnd]
        AND [PaymentPlan] = 'Monthly'
) AutoDates ([GeneratedDate]);
```

You can change the `DateEnd` parameter to something less and you will see how less months are generated.

The idea is to have `start` and `end` date for each row and depending on it to generate your months.

---

To get the records for the years use the following:

```
WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,@DateBeg AS [DateBeg]
          ,@DateEnd AS [DateEnd]
    FROM ItemDefinition DS
)
SELECT *
      ,DATENAME(MONTH ,ISNULL([GeneratedDate], [RenewalDate])) AS RenewalMonth
      ,IIF([PaymentPlan] = 'Monthly', [UnitRate], IIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), [RenewalDate], 121) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), [GeneratedDate], 121), [UnitRate], NULL))
FROM Ranges
OUTER APPLY  
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg])
    FROM 
    (
        select number 
        from master.dbo.spt_values
        where [type] = 'P'
    ) numbers
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg]) < [DateEnd]
) AutoDates ([GeneratedDate]);
```

or the following to get the year rate for the first record:

```
DECLARE @DateBeg DATE = '2019-01-01'
       ,@DateEnd DAte = '2020-12-01';


WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,@DateBeg AS [DateBeg]
          ,@DateEnd AS [DateEnd]
    FROM ItemDefinition DS
)
SELECT *
      ,DATENAME(MONTH ,ISNULL([GeneratedDate], [RenewalDate])) AS RenewalMonth
      ,IIF([PaymentPlan] = 'Monthly', [UnitRate], IIF([number] = 0, [UnitRate], NULL))
FROM Ranges
OUTER APPLY  
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg])
          ,[number]
    FROM 
    (
        select number 
        from master.dbo.spt_values
        where [type] = 'P'
    ) numbers
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, [number], [DateBeg]) < [DateEnd]
) AutoDates ([GeneratedDate], [number]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to introduce an additional table that will have a single record for a Yearly plan and 12 records for Monthly plan. For example:

```
create table PaymentPlanInterval(
    PaymentPlan VARCHAR(50),
    Interval varchar(50)
)
```

And perhaps this table may contain 2 records for Semi-annual payment plan and 4 records for quartely plan.

In order to get your desired result you should be joining your ItemDefinition table with PaymentPlanInterval. Voila.