# Running Total - Create row for months that don't have any sales in the region (1 row for each region in each month)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on the below query that I will use inside Tableau to create a line chart that will be color-coded by year and will use the region as a filter for the user. The query works, but I found there are months in regions that don't have any sales. These sections break up the line chart and I am not able to fill in the missing spaces (I am using a non-date dimension on the X-Axis - Number of months until the end of its fiscal year).

I am looking for some help to alter my query to create a row for every month and every region in my dataset so that my running total will have a value to display in the line chart. if there are no values in my table, then = 0 and update the running total for the region.

I have a dimDate table and also a Regions table I can use in the query.

My Query now, (Results sorted in Excel to view easier) [Results Table Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyCJi.png)

What I want to do; New rows highlighted in Yellow [What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfpv.png)

My Code using SQL Server:

```
SELECT b.gy, 
       b.sales_month, 
       b.region, 
       b.gs_year_total, 
       b.months_away,  
       Sum(b.gs_year_total) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY b.gy, b.region 
           ORDER BY b.months_away DESC) RT_by_Region_GY 
FROM   (SELECT a.gy, 
               a.region, 
               a.sales_month, 
               Sum(a.gy_total) Gs_Year_Total, 
               a.months_away 
        FROM   (SELECT g.val_id, 
                       g.[gs year]                                        AS GY 
                       , 
                       g.sales_month 
                       AS 
                       Sales_Month, 
                       g.gy_total, 
                       Datediff(month, g.sales_month, dt.lastdayofyear) AS 
                       months_away, 
                       g.value_type, 
                       val.region 
                FROM   uv_sales g 
                       JOIN dbo.dimdate AS dt 
                         ON g.[gs year] = dt.gsyear 
                       JOIN dimvalsummary val 
                         ON g.val_id = val.val_id 
                WHERE  g.[gs year] IN ( 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 ) 
                GROUP  BY g.valuation_id, 
                          g.[gs year], 
                          val.region, 
                          g.sales_month, 
                          dt.lastdayofyear, 
                          g.gy_total, 
                          g.value_type) a 
        WHERE  a.months_away >= 0 
               AND sales_month < Dateadd(month, -1, Getdate()) 
        GROUP  BY a.gy, 
                  a.region, 
                  a.sales_month, 
                  a.months_away) b
```

Comment: Probably something like this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155268/want-to-display-12-months-name-from-sql-server/14155821#14155821...

Comment: Thank you, I will take a closer look at the link

Comment: Many, many questions had addressed this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to envision the best method to solve without data and the meaning of all those fields. Here's a rough sketch of how one might attempt to solve it. This is not complete or tested, sorry, but I'm not sure the meaning of all those fields and don't have data to test.

Create a table called all_months and insert all the months from oldest to whatever date in the future you need.

```
    01/01/2017
    02/01/2017
    ... 
    12/01/2049
```

May need one query per region and union them together. Select the year & month from that all_months table, and left join to your other table on month. Coalesce your dollar values.

```
    select 'East' as region, 
    extract(year from m.month) as gy_year, 
    m.month as sales_month, 
    coalesce(g.gy_total, 0) as gy_total, 
    datediff(month, m.month, dt.lastdayofyear) as months_away
    from all_months m
    left join uv_sales g on g.sales_month = m.month
    --and so on
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of data and meaning. I usually try to create sample data with my question, but in this case, I was looking for what you suggested...I high-level plan. I do have a dimDate table with all dates and also a regions table with all my regions. I will start with that and then follow your outline.
Thank you!