# How to keep all records from one table, and aggregate a number from another table

Tags: sql, impala

So I'm trying to get every member for every month from one table, and sum all the claims from a different table.  The problem is, not every member has a claim every month, so those months don't appear when I'm doing.  This leads to inaccurate claim counts.

```
CTE1 as
(
select YearMonth, MemID, Flag
from month a
group by 1,2,3
)  
--Link to claim to roll up claims to yearmo

select a.Yearmonth, a.flag,count(distinct a.memid) as "MMs", sum(b.claimamount) as "Paid"
from CTE1 a
left join table1 b on a.member_id=b.member_id and a.yearmonth=b.Yearmonth
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?  I thought this is was a left join was supposed to do.

Month Table

| YearMonth | MemID | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | 1 | Y |
| 202001 | 2 | N |
| 202001 | 3 | N |

Claim Table

| ClaimID | MemID | Yearmonth | ClaimAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 202001 | $5.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 202001 | $2.00 |

Actual Result

| Yearmonth | Flag | MMs | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | Y | 1 | $5 |
| 202001 | N | 1 | $2 |

Expected Result

| Yearmonth | Flag | MMs | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001 | Y | 1 | $5 |
| 202001 | N | 2 | $2 |

How can I get an accurate count of the members?

Comment: you can add a third CTE which contains all the months that you want to appear in the final result, and select from that CTE, and do a LEFT JOIN to the other 2 CTE's. for an MSSQL example see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246795/how-to-get-all-months-in-a-query-where-one-month-has-no-matches ), or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155268/want-to-display-12-months-name-from-sql-server for a Oracle example

Comment: But my CTE 2 already has all the months I want to appear in the final result.

Essentially, CTE2 contains a record for every month for every member if they were a member, and if they have a certain flag for that month.  I want my final table to count how many members were in that month, grouped by the flag and month, and add in claims from table 1.

Comment: Create a minimal test case which shows the behavior you're describing.  `CREATE TABLE ...; INSERT ...; ... etc`  Make sure your query executes against that test case and produces the incorrect result.  Show the exact result you expected, given this specific test data.  Btw, the posted SQL looks like it has a syntax error.  Verify that the SQL in this complete test case executes without error.

Comment: And, while creating an [mre], also specify the exact DBMS you are using, and the version of it. You can even remove `toad`, because that is a client, and your SQL statement should work OK independent from the client.